# Azure application gateway for function apps

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I've an azure application `gateway-WAF`. I would like to have a web app and a function app as the backend pools.
I need to have the requests reaching the corresponding applications.
The functions are called by the web app only.

I did try from my side - based on my understanding.
I created a backend pool for the function app - web app was already a backend pool and has the listener with port 443 and associated a rule.
For function app, I've created a Multi-site listener - Function app URL as the host name with HTTPS protocol and created a path-based rule (as the basic one is for the web app). The path is defined as `/*path*/*`

When I hit the URL - `https://<*gatewayDNSname*>/apiroot/<*function*>`
I'm getting the resource has been removed or temporarily down

Comment: Having the "basic" listener and a "multi-site" listener while testing it with the same backend was the mistake. Due to some conflict, it wasn't working.
After removing the "Basic" listener and the basic rule, it worked(with multi-site listener & path-based rule associated with it). 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the replica of [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76ab2147-b967-4c99-9b26-9f5f1872e869/azure-application-gateway-for-azure-function-app?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork) thread. Please follow up the mentioned thread for updates.

Comment: Thank you. It's the same question.